# Does a SATA cable with three connectors exist?

Tags: motherboard, sata, cable

I have the this motherboard: Intel Desktop Board DX38BT - Mainboard – ATX - iX38 – LGA775 Socket – UDMA 100, Serial ATA 300 (RAID), eSATA

I have two data outputs which connect to my hard disks. I bought an additional hard disk. All three disks are SATA disks. I would like to have all three hard disks connected. Is it possible? Are there cables with two connectors on one end and one connector on the other end? I asked about it in my home computer shop and they told me not.

Comment: Please specify: Are we talking about IDE or SATA harddisks?

Comment: They are all SATA disks. I updated the questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec the board has 6 SATA and 1 PATA (IDE) connection (so you can have 2 IDE devices) so it depends on how you connect your existing 2 HDDs (and any Optical drives you have)

If your new HDD is SATA then it should have a free SATA port to connect to

Answer (score 1):

The board has 6 SATA-Connector (at least the images from Google are telling me this). Just use the next two.